# Dvb-t usb stick on debian squeeze

Tags: drivers, debian

I can't get run my dvb-t stick on debian. I installed `firmware-linux-nonfree_0.28+squeeze1_all.deb` and `linux-image-amd64` when I start `me-tv` I get the message that there is no dvb-t device connected. Same with kaffeine here is my dmesg output:

```
[  107.721266] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and 
address 7
[  107.818334] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, 
idProduct=9006
[  107.818340] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, 
SerialNumber=0
[  107.818344] usb 2-1.2: Product: DVB-T TV Stick
[  107.818347] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: ITE Technologies, Inc.
[  107.818478] usb 2-1.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[  107.821595] input: ITE Technologies, Inc. DVB-T TV Stick as /devices
/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/input/input13
[  107.821750] generic-usb 0003:048D:9006.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID 
v1.01 Keyboard [ITE Technologies, Inc. DVB-T TV Stick] on 
usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input1
```

Comment: This is supported in newer kernels, but not 2.6.32, which is current in Debian squeeze.  Are you running a backport kernel by any chance?

Comment: no i'm running 2.6.32-5. is there a solution to get it running in this kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this device is not supported in the Debian Squeeze kernel so you'll need to build the dvb device drivers yourself.

Apparently it is the same hardware as KWorld UB499-2T, and so supported in the `media/dvb/dvb-usb/it913x.c` file (with the hardware ids in `dvb-usb-ids.h` defined as `USB_VID_ITETECH` and `USB_PID_ITETECH_IT9135_9006`)

http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers

If any of this seems a bit daunting, then a better option might be to give in and purchase a dvb tuner that is already supported in your kernel:

http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices